# Open asset database with migration strategy

Tags: database, flutter, migration, sqflite

I followed this guide [Opening an asset database](https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite/doc/opening_asset_db.md) to open an asset database and to copy it to my file system but with "readOnly: true" as I want the user to modify the database inside the app.

```
  initDB() async {
    Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, "TEST.db");

    var exists = await databaseExists(path);

    if (!exists) {
      // Should happen only the first time you launch your application
      print("Creating new copy from asset");

      // Make sure the parent directory exists
      try {
        await Directory(dirname(path)).create(recursive: true);
      } catch (_) {}

      // Copy from asset
      ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(join("assets", "test.db"));
      List<int> bytes =
          data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);

      // Write and flush the bytes written
      await File(path).writeAsBytes(bytes, flush: true);
    } else {
      print("Opening existing database");
    }
    // open the database
    return await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onUpgrade: _onUpgrade);
  }
```

And this works perfectly.

But later I want to modify the asset database, e.g. adding new rows, columns or tables or even change the values from a specific already existing column. When I do that I want to update the copied database in the file system with the modified asset database. For that I use onUpgrade.

```
  _onUpgrade(Database db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) async {
    Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, "TEST.db");

    // Delete old database and load new asset database
    await deleteDatabase(path);
    try {
      await Directory(dirname(path)).create(recursive: true);
    } catch (_) {}

    ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(join("assets", "test.db"));
    List<int> bytes =
        data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);
    await new File(path).writeAsBytes(bytes, flush: true);

    // Add new table

    // Add new row or column

    // Update column
  }
```

I only know how to delete the database in the file system after a version change, but I don't want to delete the changes in the database the user did.
How can I merge the new asset database with the database in the file system? How can I add a new table, column or row? And how can I replace a column?

Comment: This feels either Too Broad or Unclear. If you have a migration system, then presumably you have "up" and "down" methods to go forwards and backwards respectively. In there you can add rows or tables, using the methods provided by your migration framework. Can you expand on what trouble you are having with that?

Comment: I don't have a migration system. I have never worked with databases or sql before. I edited my question. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: OK, thanks - that seems more specific. I will vote to reopen.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to open it with readOnly = false.

Then when you call onUpgrade you will have to run sql queries to alter the tables with the ALTER TABLE command.

```
final Future<Database> database = openDatabase(
  // Set the path to the database.
  join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'mydatabase.db'),

  onUpgrade: (db, version ...) {
    return db.execute(
      "ALTER TABLE ... ADD COLUMN ...",
    );
  },
  // Set the version to upgrade
  version: 2,
);
```